# How to filter a category in wordpress/php?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I have a php code as shown below:

`$category = get_the_category();` // Line #A

`echo '<pre>'; print_r($category); echo '</pre>';`// Line #B Added for debugging purpose

The code at Line#A retrieves post categories.

The code at the 2nd line which I have added for the debugging purpose returns the following array;

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 13085
            [name] => Cannabis
            [slug] => democracy_project_cannabis
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 13085
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => Hello World 
            [parent] => 13083
            [count] => 8
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 13085
            [category_count] => 8
            [category_description] => Good Morning
            [cat_name] => Cannabis
            [category_nicename] => democracy_project_cannabis
            [category_parent] => 13083
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 13093
            [name] => Today
            [slug] => today
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 13093
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 13093
            [category_count] => 3
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Today
            [category_nicename] => today
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what php code I need to add after Line#A so that it takes only category [name] => Today.

The code at Line#A returns the list of categories for a specific post. I just want to take only one category.

I think I need to use array_filter() method but I am not sure how I can use it.

Comment: You can do this `$category[1]["name"];`

Comment: Where ? After Line#A ?

Comment: Yes,after `$category = get_the_category();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off getting the posts you want based a specific category to begin with rather than filtering everything.

```
$term = get_term_by('name', 'Today', 'category');
if ($term) {
  $category = get_the_category($term->term_id);
} else {
  echo "Category not found";
}
```

Comment: Trying. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the returned `$category` array:

```
foreach($category as $cat) {

    if ($cat->name == 'Today') {
        //do your stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: How can we hardcode so that it takes only `category [name] => Today.` ? Lets forget foreach loop.

Comment: Probably [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) is what you are looking for. `get_term_by( 'name', 'Today')` returns the requested term object and can then be used for further processing.